# How to get the closest number from a List<Price> with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, list, numbers

I have one price matrix list, where i am storing width,length and price of the item. I want to find the greatest width and height from the input width and length. For example, Lets say,

```
Public Class ItemPrice
{
public int id{ get; set; }
public string item{ get; set; }
public int width{ get; set; }
public int height{ get; set; }
public decimal price{ get; set; }
} 

List<ItemPrice> itemorder = new List<ItemPrice>();
itemorder.Add(new ItemPrice(1,"A",24,12,$12.24));
itemorder.Add(new ItemPrice(2,"A",24,14,$16.24));
itemorder.Add(new ItemPrice(3,"A",36,12,,$18.24));
itemorder.Add(new ItemPrice(4,"A",36,14,$21.24));
```

that means it look like

```
       24      36
--------------------
12 | $12.24  $18.24
14 | $16.24  $21.24
```

How can i find the ItemPrice id 4 as a result for width=30 and height =13 ? and how can i return null value if the width = 40 and height=16?

Comment: Please be precise about the order of H en W. Post the first line of that constructor.

Comment: @HenkHolterman : I just want to know the logic behind that so thats why i haven't written constructor in my question.

Comment: And what should the return be for W=10, H=26? And for W=10, H=10 ?

Comment: But you mix up W,H and H,W. It's for being clear.

Comment: I am sorry for mixing all the things but now i have corrected..

Comment: OK. There are still some questions open from Jens and from me.

Comment: For W=10, H=26 it should return null and for W=10 , H=10 it should return Item Price Id=1

Comment: If Width matched and Height doesn't matches then it should return null and if Height matches and width doesn't, even at that case also it should return null.

Comment: have you tried my LINQ query? It meets the specified requirements, but I'll adjust it if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
// Change these as needed
int orderWidth = 1;
int orderHeight = 1;

var bestMatch = (from item in itemorder
                 where item.width >= orderWidth
                 where item.height >= orderHeight
                 orderby item.width * item.height
                 select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

This LINQ query filters out all items whose size are less than the ordered size. Then it orders the remaining items in ascending order. Finally, it picks the first item (== smallest item), or null.

**EDIT**

Here's an updated solution based on the sum of the sides of each item.

```
int orderWidth = 4;
int orderHeight = 4;

int orderSum = orderWidth + orderHeight;

var bestMatch = (from item in itemorder
                 where item.width >= orderWidth
                 where item.height >= orderHeight
                 let itemSum = item.width + item.height
                 let difference = Math.Abs(orderSum - itemSum)
                 orderby difference
                 select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This solution has the potential flaw of returning a poorly sized solution. Say, for example, you have a two rectangles - 5 x 1,000 & 6 x 7 - if you're searching for a rectangle greater than 4 x 4 then the 5 x 1,000 would be returned when perhaps the 6 x 7 would be a better match. The `orderby` line is perhaps better expressed as `orderby item.width * item.height` as this will return the closest matching size.

Comment: @Enigmativity that's crazy, did you figure that out just by looking at my code? Amazing.

Comment: @StevenLiekens - Thats because this solution doesnt really provide a correct answer. The original request was to provide an a close as possible approach, this solution provides a 'largest area' approach. If you imagine width and height to simply form points, you can utilize a technique described in for example this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907567/filter-points-xy-by-distance-with-linq

Comment: @Polity I'm not sure how to imagine width and height as anything other than the distance between points? EDIT: I see what you mean now.

Comment: @StevenLiekens - Yes, just by looking at your code. 'Twas easy. :-)

Comment: @Polity I came up with a different solution, could you review it please?

Comment: You can speed things up a little by removing both `Math.Sqrt` calls :)

Comment: @Rawling I'll be the first to admit that I'm not a math genius, but wouldn't I also have to delete the `Math.Pow` calls?

Comment: Actually Steven I'm wrong. You could drop the `Sqrt` if you were just looking for the longest/shortest diagonal, but since you're looking for the closest to a given value, it might give you the wrong result.

Comment: Well it's working, so you were right the first time. Even just looking for the closest sum of both sides is giving me the right answer every time. I don't know why, but oh well.